# how to get count of days when it not ran on Target date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an sample data like this :

```
DECLARE @T Table (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(10), DOB DATE)

INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (1,'Mohan','2016-11-11')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (2,'Raj','2016-11-07')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (3,'Manny','2016-10-30')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (4,'kamal','2016-11-01')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (5,'Raj','2016-11-08')
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Name,DOB) VALUES (6,'Manasa','2016-11-10')
```

My question is when I run the query on this table on Sunday (i.e 06/11/2016)

For example :

```
Select Count(*), Cnt  
from @T      /* how to write logic for missing days */
```

My output :

```
Cnt   Days
6    0 Days
```

Same thing when I run it on Thursday (i.e 06/11/2016)

```
Cnt   Days
6     4 Days
```

How I need to get this one. Every Sunday it will run if it ran on Saturday it should show 6 days and Sunday to Sunday calculation.

Please suggest some way of doing this - I'm unable to move forward

Comment: I'm unable to get what you mean by numbers table or tally table @MitchWheat

Comment: But how can numbers and tally table useful in date calculating @MitchWheat

Comment: if I take on date numbers it will give of whole start and end date but here I'm looking to get Sunday to Monday only week if I ran my query on Friday then it will show 5 days if ran my query on Sunday it will show 0 like that I need to get @MitchWheat

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here - your select query references a column that doesn't exist in your source data. Can you rewrite to give us queries that work?

Comment: for that Days column only I'm looking for solution if I execute this query on Sunday count should be zero and if I execute query on Thursday I need to get 4 days ..so we need to count from sunday @Beno

Comment: So.. `Select Count(*), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1
 from @T`?

Comment: Is it correct `Thursday (i.e 06/11/2016)` ?

Comment: thanks @Prdp I have got cleared my doubt

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of days since Sunday, you can use the `DATEPART` function to get the day of the week as an integer with Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7. So for this case:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1 
FROM @T
```